# Same query syntax for 2 types of users

Tags: php, mysql

This query selects all users who have their "user_expire" row "B1month".

```
$oneMonthUsersData = mysql_query("SELECT username,email FROM user WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),date_created) > 30 AND user_expire = 'B1month'");
while ($oneMonthUsers = @mysql_fetch_array($oneMonthUsersData)) {
    $deletedUsers = $deletedUsers.",".$oneMonthUsers['username'];
    $deletedUsersEmails[] = $oneMonthUsers['email'];
}
```

How should I format the syntax If I want this same query to also select all users who have their "user_expire" row "C1month" along with the ones having "B1month"?

Comment: Use `in` and provide a list.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following query:

```
SELECT username,email FROM user WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),date_created) > 30 AND (user_expire = 'B1month' OR user_expire = 'C1month')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT username, email 
FROM user 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),date_created) > 30 
     AND user_expire IN('B1month', 'C1month')
```

OR

```
SELECT username, email 
FROM user 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),date_created) > 30 
     AND (user_expire = 'B1month' OR user_expire = 'C1month')
```

But first code has better performance, I think